# unixODBC error IM001

Tags: python, sql-server, freetds, unixodbc

I get the following error when trying to do any simple query.  I just can't figure out what's changed.

Here is an example of the sqlalchemy (Elixir) class:

```
class Song(Entity):
    using_options(tablename='tbSongs', autoload=True)
    using_table_options(schema='apra')
```

The database connection is ok and the classes construct ok because I can do `dir(Song)` and see all the correct columns.  However, a simple query won't work.

Here is a query on that class and the resulting output:

```
>>> songs = Song.query.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1729, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1839, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1854, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1399, in execute
    params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1532, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1640, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1633, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 325, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (Error) ('IM001', '[IM001] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver does not support this function (0) (SQLColAttribute)') 'SELECT [tbSongs_1].[ID_Song] AS [apra_tbSongs_ID_Song], [tbSongs_1].[Album] AS [apra_tbSongs_Album], [tbSongs_1].[Title] AS [apra_tbSongs_Title], [tbSongs_1].[Composer] AS [apra_tbSongs_Composer], [tbSongs_1].[Performer] AS [apra_tbSongs_Performer], [tbSongs_1].[TrackNumber] AS [apra_tbSongs_TrackNumber], [tbSongs_1].[Duration] AS [apra_tbSongs_Duration], [tbSongs_1].[RecordLabel] AS [apra_tbSongs_RecordLabel], [tbSongs_1].[Notes] AS [apra_tbSongs_Notes], [tbSongs_1].[Class] AS [apra_tbSongs_Class], [tbSongs_1].[SongID] AS [apra_tbSongs_SongID], [tbSongs_1].[Deleted] AS [apra_tbSongs_Deleted] \nFROM apra.[tbSongs] AS [tbSongs_1]' ()
>>>
```

Setup details:

- 32bit Arch Linux
- Python 2.7.2
- sqlalchemy 0.7.2
- elixir 0.7.1
- FreeTDS 0.82-5
- unixodbc 2.3.0-1

/etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[ODBC Drivers]
tds = Installed
[tds]
Driver = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

/etc/odbc.ini:

```
[ODBC]
Trace = 0
[DBNAME]
Driver = TDS
Trace = No
Server = xx.xx.xx.xx\dbname
Database = dbname
Port = 1433
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the query and the versions of sqlalchemy and the driver.

Comment: @rocksportrocker I have added the info

Comment: Maybe you should ask at the sqlalchemy mailinglist, see http://www.sqlalchemy.org/support.html.The sql statement looks sane to me.

Comment: thanks @rocksportrocker I'll do that

Answer (score 1):

I have this error as well and downgrading to unixODBC 2.2.12 fixes it for me (note I can't get PyOBDC to build with 2.2.14, has to be 2.2.12).    I'm fairly troubled by the state of the newer releases of ODBC tools for unix (Freetds 0.91 is very problematic as well).

Comment: If its something you think is unixODBC fault, let me know on the support mailing list. 2.2.14 is now 3 years old.

Comment: Hi Nick -  I'd like to use 2.3.0, but we receive the same error as that of this topic, which would appear to be based on unixODBC specifically.  I also have other issues, which may be freetds/pyodbc specific, including http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=212 .   The authors of PyODBC and FreeTDS are generally entirely unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing prepackaged FreeTDS, unixODBC and pyodbc. Rebuilding from sources using version 0.91, 2.3.0 and 2.1.9 respectively has worked for me but it can be a tricky process. I have covered it in some detail on a recent thread on SQLAlchemy group at http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/971e068032d51dd5

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have no more time to test with Linux for now.  Instead, I just deployed on OSX because it just works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a ODBC trace of this occuring. I have only just become aware of this problem and I can't (at the moment) reproduce it. So if you can send me the log of it happing it should be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Oh, by the way, if you want to send it (the trace) to me as nick at lurcher dot org I wisee what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Nick, I've been bugging you on the list too.  I have not been able to reproduce this again yet, but if and when I can I will email you on the list or via here.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, my suspiscion is that some form of corruption is going on. The error will happen if the driver manager believes the driver doesn't support either SQLColAttribute or SQLColAttributes. But just what is causing it is hard to say. But given I suspect corruption, maybe try using something like valgrind to see if something odd is going on.